# Как разделить товары по категориям?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Требуется разделить товары на категории, на странице товаров - чтобы шёл заголовок категории, по центру, а дальше товары из неё, как на блок-схеме ниже.

Сайт на CMS Wordpress, установлен бесплатный плагин - WooCommerce.

Ссылка на сайт: [bb-talkin.ru](https://www.bb-talkin.ru)

Блок-схема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У woocommerce есть шорткоды, которые вам могут помочь в этом вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например [вот так](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" cat_operator="AND"]
```

Comment: Дальше можете смотреть варианты и менять под свои задачи, примеров там много.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. Если укажу лимит 0, то лимита не будет?

Comment: -1 без лимита, 0 это 0

Comment: но тут есть один минус, если нужно сделать проверку на наличие товаров, чтоб не получилось так, что товаров нет, а заголовок есть

Comment: А как убрать дублирование всего каталога ниже?

Comment: не однозначный вопрос

Comment: Как минимум не использовать этот шорткод на странице магазина, то есть создать отдельную страницу без шорткода, который отвечает за стандартный вывод. Почему-то мне кажется что вы сейчас там такое "накодите" )))

Comment: Я прописал только шорт-коды категорий, а ниже он дублирует все товары. Хотелось бы это убрать. Вот ссылка: http://bb-talkin.ru/shop/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87630/discussion-between-garicko-and-eugene-v).